# recharts cannot draw two independent lines

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, recharts

I want to draw two independent or separate lines with recharts.

Here is my data

```js
const series = [
  {
    name: '0',
    data: [
      {x: "07/16/20 01:50", y: "0.397"},
      {x: "07/16/20 02:51", y: "0.480"},
      {x: "07/16/20 02:52", y: "0.416"},
      {x: "07/16/20 02:53", y: "0.396"},
      {x: "07/16/20 02:54", y: "0.418"},
      {x: "07/16/20 02:55", y: "0.390"}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: '1',
    data: [
      {x: "07/16/20 04:54", y: "0.384"},
      {x: "07/16/20 05:57", y: "0.432"}
    ],
  }
];
```

There is no common points.

```js
<LineChart>
  {series.map((s, index) => {
    return (
      <Line key={index} strokeWidth={3} dot={{fill: '#4D92F5', r: 5}} activeDot={{
        onClick: () => {
          handleDotClick()
        }
      }} name={s.name} dataKey="y" data={s.data}/>
    )
  })}
  <CartesianGrid horizontal={false} stroke="rgba(16, 147, 200, 0.08)"/>
  <XAxis
    name='Time'
    dataKey="x"/>
  <YAxis
     type="number" dataKey="y"/>
</LineChart>
```

[image]

Why for heaven sake it gives me the common points? And why it doesn't draw it till the end of the row? If I left only one line it draws it fine till the end.

It drives me nuts.

Comment: @trixn second line points - according the chart- to 07/16/20 at 01:50. The same starting point is for the first line. Why it starts here? It shouldn't. It should start at 04:54. Isn't it plain to see?

Comment: Calm down I haven't stared at it as long as you probably did. Now I got it. The strings you are using als values for the x-Axis aren't suitable. How should recharts know the order of them? You need to convert them to something that can be sorted. Unix timestamps could work for example.

Comment: @trixn I didn't meant to be rude with you, sorry. I usually (not in this piece of code format my time using  xValue = moment(xValue).format('MM/DD/YY hh:mm');  is it ok?

Comment: nope, wrong approach.     const series = [
        {
            name: '0',
            data: [{x: "1", y: "0.397"},
                {x: "2", y: "0.480"},
                {x: "3", y: "0.416"},
                {x: "4", y: "0.396"},
                {x: "5", y: "0.418"},
                {x: "6", y: "0.390"}]
        },
        {
            name: '1',
            data: [{x: "10", y: "0.384"},
                {x: "15", y: "0.432"}],
        }
    ];  --- it starts with wrong values too.

Comment: As far as I can see recharts supports to kinds of axis. `category` and `number` where category is ordered by the order in which the stings appear in the series. Recharts doesn't interpret is as something that has an inherent order. Numbers are sorted by their value instead.

Comment: Also you need to set `allowDuplicatedCategory={false}` on your `XAxis` component and if you are using numbers for the x-Axis you need to set `type="number"`.

Comment: @trixn I think you leaded me to the right way. I put numbers without brackets into x like 1 and 2 and so on, and set the type of xAxis to number. It showed me 2 separate lines! I need to make it with time. A huge step for me. Thank you!

Comment: @trixn once again, thank you. I change the x values to epoch moment(xValue).format('x'); convert it to a number and set the type of the xAxis to number. It seems it works!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you convert the X values to a number, then you can use this XAxis:

```
<XAxis
  type="number"
  dataKey="x"
  domain={['dataMin', 'dataMax']}
  tickFormatter={(tick)=>new Date(tick).toISOString()}
/>
```

How ever you are generating the data for the graph, just do new Date(x).getTime() to return a number (milliseconds since the unix epoch):

```
data: [
  {x: new Date("07/16/20 01:50").getTime(), y: "0.397"},
  {x: new Date("07/16/20 02:51").getTime(), y: "0.480"},
  {x: new Date("07/16/20 02:52").getTime(), y: "0.416"},
  {x: new Date("07/16/20 02:53").getTime(), y: "0.396"},
  {x: new Date("07/16/20 02:54").getTime(), y: "0.418"},
  {x: new Date("07/16/20 02:55").getTime(), y: "0.390"}
]
```